# Sum from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, function, sum

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets contained within it at the moment, and one master worksheet which will summarise data from the individual sheets. For my master worksheet, is there a way to sum individual cells?

For instance, if i select the sum function and select the cells I2:I4 on one worksheet, is there a way I can select a random cell which contains the data I need, say J6? Because as of now it doesn't let me select individual cells on separate worksheets as part of one formula. Any advice on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to add any number of individual cells to a sum formula:  `=SUM($F$3:$F$11,Sheet1!$D$3,Sheet2!$F$6,Sheet3!$E$12,$L$4:$M$16)` - anything that doesn't have a sheet name is on the same sheet as the formula.

Comment: You can even use a 3D formula in there:  `=SUM($F$3,Sheet1:Sheet3!$G$13)` - this will sum the value in `F3` on the current sheet and `G13` on all sheets between `Sheet1` and `Sheet3` in the tab order (so including `Sheet2`)

Comment: Thanks @Darren Bartrup-Cook, however now it is turning up a #VALUE! error. For example, using the following formula =SUM('5.10.2018'!I2  '8.10.2018'!I3), and knowing the cells selected to be the correct ones, I continue to get an error. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: For that 3D formula, would there be a way to filter it? For example, to have it sum data by account name

Comment: You missed the comma in the formula separating the two cell references `=SUM('5.10.2018'!I2,'8.10.2018'!I3)`.  I don't think there's a way to filter it - you'd need to use `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` for that which doesn't work on 3D formula (as far as I know).

Comment: Thank you, silly mistake to forget the comma lol. I know its a lot to ask, but do you think you'd be able to demonstrate how the sumif function would work? I've tried to include but have had no luck so far

Comment: See [3D SUMIFS](https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets)

Comment: [SUMPRODUCT](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html) may also come in handy - it's mentioned in the link from @Scott.

Comment: mind sharing your solution with others in the answers tab? ( :